# Arrange a list of multiple columns into a matrix in Python

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a set of data in the form:

#  first block

```
1 6 11 

2 7 12

3 8 13

4 9 14

5 10 15 ...
```

# second block

```
17 22 27 

18 23 28

19 24 29

20 25 30

21 26 31 ...
```

# so on for arbitrarily many blocks

where each block does not necessarily have the same number of columns but the column lengths in each block are the same, say N long, so that in this case N=5. How can I arrange this list of blocks of columns so that my result will look like:

```
1 6 11 17 22 27

2 7 12 18 23 28

3 8 13 19 24 29

4 9 14 20 25 30

5 10 15 21 26 31 ...
```

Please let me know if this question can be clarified and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: `list.extend` may be helpful in this case.

Comment: Are you reading the data from a file? What kind of file is it, .csv? What do you intend to use it for?

Comment: Still don't understand your question, do you want store a list to file or import list from file?

Comment: The blocks of columns are all in the same file and are separated by one line of vertical space. The file needs to be read and reformatted into the form shown in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you read the number block from a file. But just lets assume you already have
the data.

And also assuming that the number of columns of the resulting blocks is irrelevant, the issue here is maintain the number `N`. right?

```
block_1 = [
    [1, 6, 11],
    [2, 7, 12],
    [3, 8, 13],
    [4, 9, 14],
    [5, 10, 15]
]

block_2 = [
    [17, 22, 27],
    [18, 23, 28],
    [19, 24, 29],
    [20, 25, 30],
    [21, 26, 31]
]

all_numbers = []

new_block = []

rows = len(block_1) # Since the column length is the same. 
                    # Either block_1 or block_2 works here.

# Get all numbers and sort.
for row in block_1:
    all_numbers.extend(row)

for row in block_2:
    all_numbers.extend(row)

all_numbers.sort()

# Build the matrix.
matrix = []
for i in range(0, len(all_numbers), rows):
    matrix.append(all_numbers[i:i+rows])

# Set the correct place for collumns.
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    r = []
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        r.append(matrix[j][i]) 
    new_block.append(r)

print(new_block)
```

Answer (score 0):

i consider ur bringing from file or list

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as data1:
    a=data1.readlines()
with open('file2.txt','r') as data2:
    b=data2.readlines()

# if list just intialize them to a,b
with open('output.txt','a') as out:
    for i,j in zip(a,b):
        out.write(i+" "+j)
```

for lists:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
b=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
output=[]
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    output.append(i+j)
print output

#[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, the data is in a file that needs to be read from, but every block of columns is in the same file. So, by this approach, each block of columns would need to be defined as a,b,... But there are a very large number of blocks in the file. How could I avoid having to define each block? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This response extends the accepted answer by Raydel Miranda. I needed to be able to organize an arbitrary number of blocks, all of which were in the same file, into the matrix form described. In order to do this, consider a separate file `block_defenitions.py` where some number of blocks are defined as variables. Then I adjusted the accepted answer code to be able to take in the total number of blocks from the file and formats them into the desired matrix and writes this matrix to an output file:

```
 def format():
    import block_definitions 

    all_numbers = []

    new_block = []

    rows = len(block_definitions.block_1)

    blocks = block_definitions.blocks


    for i in range(0,len(blocks)):
        for row in blocks[i]:
            all_numbers.extend(row)

    matrix = []

    for i in range(0,len(all_numbers), rows):
        matrix.append(all_numbers[i:i+rows])

    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        r = []
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            r.append(matrix[j][i])
        new_block.append(r)

    with open("final_output.txt",'w') as output:
        output.write(str(matrix))
    output.close()
```

Note that `blocks` is a list of all the block variables defined in `block_definitions.py`.